# what is the best way to terminate a connection in indy10?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

im using indy10 for my communications, and sometimes when a client disconnects it raises an exception, i was wondering whats the safest way to disconnect a connection (TIdContext) ?

and what should i do on the OnDisconnect even and similar?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Raising an exception is normal behavior.  Indy is designed to make heavy use of exceptions, not only for error handling but also for internal notifications and such.  `OnDisconnect` is fired when `TIdTCPServer` detects that the connection is finished, either because the client disconnected (and `TIdTCPServer` handled the exception for you) or because an uncaught exception occured in your `OnExecute` handler code.  Either way, use `OnDisconnect` to perform any cleanup you need.  `TIdTCPServer` will close the socket for you after the `OnDisconnect` event handler exits.

Comment: ok, and if i want to close the whole socket? should i just do TIdTCPServer.Active := False? or there is some cleaning up i should do? 
thanks

Comment: What "whole socket" are you referring to exactly?  A single client, or the entire server?  If you want to disconnect individual clients, then simply call `Disconnect()` on their `TIdTCPConnection` object.  Setting `Active := False` deactivates the entire service and automatically disconnects any connected clients.  `OnDisconnect` will still be fired in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add something about sockets internal work (TCP) that I know:

All that **server** and **client** does, they sends pieces of data to each other. **Server** differs from the **client** only so that he is passive until any **client** don't send a connection request first. But if **client** want or forced to break the connection, all is need to do is stop send data to **server**. To gracefully close a connection **client** may send special data about this event, like saying "goodbay" by phone, but this is not absolutely required. Simply imagine phone call from you (**client**) to any service (**server**). You start conversation with "hello" and service worker responds. If you accidently press reset on your phone, call will lost. But service still continue his work. And you may make call it again. Nothing bad happens from that.

All what you need to care about is stable and correct **client** and **server** work by itself. Check incorrect sending and receiving data. Try to reconnect when it needed from **client**. If some exception throws inside **client** it must be processed as needed and its normal situation when current connection was lost by such forced events.

Everything else has already answered by **Remy Lebeau**.